# T-SQL: how to use SUM() with GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum

I have a very basic question:

I have this code which works and returns me **23 rows**:

```
select 
Issue_ID
,sum(HoursSpent) as TimeSpent
--,DateClosed 
from SixMonthsReview
where StaffAssigned = 'Teddy Bear'
and DateClosed between '2018-07-01 06:36:26.790' and '2018-08-01 06:36:26.790'
group by Issue_ID
```

But if I uncomment line  4 I receive an error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'SixMonthsReview.DateClosed' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

so I add `DateClosed` into the `GROUP BY` but now **40 rows** are returned and I can see doubles.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: well....nowhere....you are just adding another column to group by for....so if you want every combination of `issue_id`, `DateClosed` and how many hours were spent there is different than the total hours spent for every issue_id

Comment: Do tell what you are trying to accomplish.  Posting a broken query without telling what you want will get you nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group by Issue_ID` means a row per `Issue_ID`, so you need to tell it how to show `DateClosed` as a single value. Perhaps you want `MAX(DateClosed)` for example?